# Exchange 2007 Mailbox disable feature

Tags: exchange-2007

In an Exchange 2007 environment, if the AD associated to the mailbox account is disabled, does that mean if someone sends an email to the email address, the email will not be received in Exch mailbox coz the AD is already disabled?  If I want to avoid disabling the mailbox due to it will be marked for removal, can I just simple disable all the Mailbox features? Reason being is that in case there's a specific email I need to retrieve, I guess I can just simply enable the AD account and enable the mailbox features?  Appreciate everyone's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent the old email address to be used as even if you keep the account open, I would remove all know email alias with the mailbox (and create a fake one as you need one) and hide the user in the GAL.

A even better approch would be to export the user mailbox to a pst and archive it. You will save on backup time and space for your exchange.

Comment: you're right. better approach would be to export to pst.  Thank you.